# Using "hold" in the sense of "taking place"

Tags: word-usage

Are these examples right:

> "The conference is held in ",
>
> "it [the event] holds in "
>
> "they held a meeting on Monday."

Do I have to use the passive as in the first example?

Comment: Yes, you do have to use the passive in such contexts. It's fine to say *X is held in/at/on [some place or time]*, but it's completely non-idiomatic to say *X **holds** there/then* - you'd have to switch to, say, ***takes place***.

Comment: In essence, even though there is no explicit mention of the doer in passive voice, it is implied that *somebody* “holds” a conference. Incorrectly converting the sentence into active voice, i.e. losing the *doer*, makes the event *its own organizer*, which is interpreted differently.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples

> The conference is **held** in *a big city*.

implies repetition in the future, where as

> The conference was **held** in *New York City*.  *( past )*
>   The conference is **being held** *in Atlanta this year.*  *( present or future )*
>   They are **holding**  the conference *in Atlanta this year.*  *( present or future )*
>   They **will hold** the conference *in Atlanta this year.*  *( future )*

It is incorrect to use

> it [the event] holds in

but rather

> The dam **holds in** water.

For usage of a past meeting

> They **held** a meeting on Monday.
>   They **held** the conference *in Atlanta this year*.

are correct, it is also often said

> They **had** a meeting on Monday.
>   They **had** the conference *in Atlanta this year.*